# Importing excel file to datagridview using openFileDialog

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform with a load button.  When I click the load, I pick a file I want to load into the datagridview.  When I click the file, the right number of rows seem to populate , but no content shows.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  "Acronyms" is the name of my excel tab/sheet.

```
   private void btnImport_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "XLS files (*.xls, *.xlt)|*.xls;*.xlt|XLSX files (*.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xltx, *.xltm)|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xltx;*.xltm|ODS files (*.ods, *.ots)|*.ods;*.ots|CSV files (*.csv, *.tsv)|*.csv;*.tsv|HTML files (*.html, *.htm)|*.html;*.htm";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog.FileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyConnection.Open();
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Acronyms$]", MyConnection);
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dgvExcelList.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure the columns you created via the GUI for the DataGridView has a DataProperty value filled in.